# How to just use macOS's command key?

Tags: osx, modifier-key

Can one use macOS's Command Key (⌘) as a separate modifier key from `ctrl` and `meta`?

My specific question is, is it possible to use `⌘+Q` to quit emacs without altering the existing keybindings? I have something like this in mind:

```
(bind-key "\⌘-q" 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)
```

This particular code doesn't work, of course.

I've been using emacs longer than I've been using macOS and don't want a whole-sale change like that `mac-key-mode` offers.  I just want a selected set of mac shortcuts to work on emacs.

The version of emacs I uses is the one from the `emacs-mac` cask package of homebrew. The package description includes

```
railwaycat/emacsmacport/emacs-mac: stable emacs-27.2-mac-8.3, HEAD
YAMAMOTO Mitsuharu's Mac port of GNU Emacs
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/
```

**Edit:** I've started wonder whether my question is the same as

[Carbon Emacs ⌘-shortcuts in Mituharu-Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29014/carbon-emacs-shortcuts-in-mituharu-emacs?rq=1)

If so, the only solution seems to be for me to use a different emacs package than `emacs-mac` . . . .

Comment: Which Emacs are you using?  By default the Cmd key is set to act as `super` and Cmd+q is bound to `ns-power-off`, which quits Emacs.app.

Comment: @d125q Thanks! but I don't find the `ns-` functions on my emacs.  I looked it up in `M-x describe-function` and `M-x describe-variable` but no functions of variables start with a `ns-` prefix.  What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `ns-command-modifier` is `super`. So you can use `(bind-key "s-q" 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)`

*Update*:
As you said you are using emacs-mac, and the default value of `mac-command-modifier` is `meta`. I suggest to change mac-command-modifier to super or hyper (i.e. `(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)`) and use `mac-option-modifier` as `meta`.

Besides, the corresponding prefixes and modifiers are: `M- (meta), C- (control), S- (shift), A- (alt), H- (hyper), and s- (super)`. For more details, please see the doc of `bind-key` and `edmacro-mode`.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't find the `ns-` functions on my emacs.  I looked it up in `M-x describe-function` and `M-x describe-variable` but no functions of variables start with a `ns-` prefix.  What does that mean?

Comment: are you using emacs-mac? what about `mac-command-modifier`

Comment: Yes, I am using emacs-mac .  mac-command-modifier is currently set to `meta`. By the way, `(bind-key "s-q" 'save-buffer-kill-terminal)` doesn't seem to make any changes.

Comment: Yes becasuse the value is `meta` not `super`.

Comment: @Ryo I have update the modifiers and prefixes in the answers. I suggest to change `mac-command-modifier` to `super` or `hyper`(i.e. `(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)`) and use `mac-option-modifier` as `meta`.

Comment: Thanks!  Adding `(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)` and `(bind-key "s-q" 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)` has worked!  Could you add `(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)`  to your answer above to help future visitors to stackexchange?

Comment: Hi @Ryo, added it.